# Remove Lit Supplemental Restraint System Dash Light

Tags: subaru, forester, supplemental-restraint-system

Subaru Forester 2009 - Seatbelt light is lit on dash. Have disconnected fittings from under the seat and cleaned them by spraying with WD Contact I want to remove light from dash. Can I do that with one of the scanners on the
market?

Comment: Are you saying that the warning light that reminds you to fasten your seat belt is lit?  Is it meant to go out when you fasten your seatbelt?

Comment: No they go out when fastened. This a specific red warning indicator saying 'Seatbelt'

Comment: Can you add a photo of the dash with the warning light, I can’t find anything in the owners manual about that warning light - https://subarucore.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/03200127/Forester-2009_2-Owners-manual.pdf